# i2c accessing at user space issue, How to solve this ..?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, i2c

```
WARNING: at kernel/irq/manage.c:274 0xa01aa01b()                                
Unbalanced enable for IRQ 10                                                    
Modules linked in:                                                              
Backtrace: no frame pointer                                                     
---[ end trace 5cce32c8b5df3d34 ]---
```

When I run my application program its giving this error what does this mean and how to solve..?please guide me in detail.

Comment: You kernel (whatever version and patch it is) is buggy.

Comment: @CL. Based on the line number of the warning(274), it looks like v2.6.32.xx. Most likely a vendor-tree or a patched-kernel with some untested driver that is causing this.

Answer (score 2):

Checking the kernel source(**[kernel/irq/manage.c:274](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.32/kernel/irq/manage.c#L266)**), we can see that this warning print is triggered in **`enable_irq()`**. This happens when trying to enable an already enabled IRQ i.e. without it being disabled first.

If you are getting this warning as a result of running some user-space program, then you need to check the logic of the driver that this user-space program interacts with and fix the unnecessary enabling of **`IRQ 10`** in that driver.

Apart from polluting the kernel logs, this warning is pretty much safe to ignore as it does not affect the immediate functionality. However it **does** indicate a deeper problem in your program's (or the underlying driver's) state machine logic.